People hiding while a spaceship vacuums up other people
I am trying to identify a movie. There was a scene where people are hiding downhill, behind the bushes. And they witness how an alien's spaceship is like 'vacuuming' the people from the ground up. The abducted people will then be stored in a certain area of the spaceship where they will be randomly eaten.
The film ended when a man sacrificed himself (I am not sure if he sacrificed himself or just threw the bomb to the mouth of the spaceship) using a bomb and blew up the entire ship.

Wasn't there a scene like this in the remake of War of the Worlds?

When did you see the movie? What year or decade do you think it came out in. What language was the film in?

@JamesMcLeod it can be a match.

Please provide more detail, as per current stats its matching with many films.

The second paragraph sounds like Independence Day.

Hello! I researched your answers one by one. And it came out War of the Worlds. Thank youuu!

@JamesMcLeod submit it as an answer, as it is right now. So that it can be accepted.

This scene appears somewhat as described in the 2005 remake of The War of the Worlds.
The protagonist is being sucked out of a cage. He grabs a soldier's bandolier containing some grenades as he is lifted off the ground. His body disappears into the suction device, but the other people in the cage pull him back. As he lands on the ground, he spits out the pins from the grenades and they go off, destroying the tripod's control room.

That was my first thought, but the grenades weren't at the end of the film.

Agreed that it doesn't end the film, but it does lead to the beginning of the end. And... the OP says in one of the comments under the question that this is the one, which I find a compelling reason to retain my answer.

Could it be Skyline?
IMDB synopsis:  

Strange lights descend on the city of Los Angeles, drawing people
  outside like moths to a flame where an extraterrestrial force
  threatens to swallow the entire human population off the face of the
  Earth.

